# Kafka Consumer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

Currently i'm implementing the Kafka Queue with Node.js. I can able to create the simple API in Express and push the data into  Kafka(producer).

I'm currently struck with the fetching the data from Kafka and I'm using the Kafka-node library for node.js.

I need to expose the consumer as API or backend service.

So anyone please help me out.

Comment: First of all your question is not clear. Then please share some code so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a consumer using `kafka-node`: https://blog.mimacom.com/blog/2017/04/07/apache-kafka-with-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

try this one "Getting started with NodeJS and Kafka
" - https://nodewebapps.com/2017/11/04/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-kafka/